# How a website should handle a database crash

Tags: php, database, crash, web

I am currently creating a website in php that has a database backend (can be either MySQL or SQL Server) and I realized recently that if my database crashes at any time, my website will not run properly and probably cause some headaches.

So what is the proper thing to display on the website if my database (or any crucial outside component) goes down? My particular website relies heavily on its database and will be almost useless without it.

One option I have been told is to email the website admin and display a Error 500 page that says something is wrong with the server and basically make the website unusable till the issue is fixed.  Is there anything else I could do to work around this problem? Are there any ways to design a website so that the database (any crucial component) crashing isn't an issue?

I am looking for general rules of thumb as well as specific examples of how people have worked around this in the past.  Also, these examples don't just have to be for my website example.

Comment: You could add a redundant database and use that in the event the first one crashes. Of course this adds the headache of making sure the two dbs are synchronized, which might be worth the hassle - or not.

Comment: I think the HTTP 500 error is pretty much the standard. Not sure what else you expect to be able to do, with the exception of only using the DB when necessary (thus keeping most parts of your site "working"). As a side note, are you sure your website needs a DB ***server***? A simple SQLite db might suffice and reduce your dependencies on external systems. Depends on your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have one database server, and the website cannot work without it's database, there is no magic : you'll have to display some sort of **nice error page**, **informing the users** there is a technical problem and that the website will come back shortly.

Generally speaking :

- Chances of such a problem are pretty low
- If your website is a *normal one*, people will tend to accept a problem once in a while, especially if you communicate about it.

If you can afford it *(and have the technical knowledge to set this up)*, you could use two database servers, with replication *(MySQL supports this)* between them : one master, which you use, and a slave, that's considered as a backup.

Then, if the master falls, your application will use the slave.

Of course, this will greatly reduce the risks of a database-related problem (having two servers crash at the same time is quite unlikely), but you'll still have problems with all other components -- like your webserver : if you only have one, you might want to consider using two, with the second one as a fallback.

After that, if you still have money *(and think you need an even better uptime for your website)*, you'll want to think about the case when your datacenter has a problem -- setting up server in two separate locations...

Answer (score 2):

1. The proper thing to display is a simple "oops" error message that gives away no information that would be helpful to hackers.  Something along the lines of "We're experiencing technical difficulties" or "website unavailable".  [This is for security purposes](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Improper_Error_Handling).
2. It would be good to have an error logging and notification system in place to notify an administrator in case of a crash.  That would be fairly simple to write, but I'm sure there are already libraries that handle this.  (There's a tutorial with code samples at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/404403-website-error-pages-with-php-auto-mailer/  and a simpler example at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp)
3. There are ways to design the architecture of your web site to handle a database component crashing. It's not architecting your website, it's architectin the whole environment. For example, database clustering for high availability (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster).  It's not cheap.

Overall, you just need to ensure that you're doing your error handling properly.  A database crash is a classic example ofr why we need error handling.  There are plenty of resources and guidance for this.

http://www.google.com/search?q=Error+Handling+Guidelines&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1

***Edit***

I found this and thought it was a very nice resource for answering how to handle the errors:

http://www.nyphp.org/PHundamentals/7_PHP-Error-Handling

Answer (score 1):

It is considered best practice to return a HTTP 500 status code in the event that your database being down, or any other crippled service, prevents your website from functioning properly.  Depending on your websites functionality, this could be on a page by page basis or site wide.  For example, your "About Us" page may not need database capabilities while your search page would.  You could thus keep the "About Us" page up and running but return a 500 status code when someone goes to your search page.

Do not give any technical information about why the site is not working to the end user.  This could be a security risk.

If you are using apache, this document will tell you how to setup custom error pages:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html

I recommend you use plain HTML for your 500 status code pages.  You can also have your PHP pages send a 500 status code via the header() function, documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php