# Check if MySQL server is running before retriving data from it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What is the correct way of checking if the MySQL server is up and running before trying to retrieving data from it ?

I'm using PHP and MySQLI in the object orientated way.

I'm semi-new to MySQLI and managed to write something useful for my website. A voting system.

I have some code on my website that retrieves data from the MySQL server and displays it on the website.

This works fine as long at the MySQL server is up and running and are able to connect to it.

But if i turn off the MySQL server or otherwise my PHP code is not able to connect to the SQL server my website hangs for a while until timeout and then part of my website is not displayed.

Comment: generally you don't ever turn the db server off

Comment: @Dagon why not? Maintenance, update, whatever. This is not the point anyways.

Comment: Are you just asking how to check that the DB is available? Or are you asking how to handle the case when the DB is unavailable? if the latter, look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185537/how-a-website-should-handle-a-database-crash

Comment: @knoight If i run "new mysqli(...)" and the server is down there is a 30 seconds delay before timeout. Making the website slow. I want my website to run normally just without the voting system part when the MySQL is down and not having to wait 30 seconds and missing the code on my website that comes after "new mysqli(...)".

Comment: @Lukas you are confusing a DB server with a bike. There are NO maintenance, update or whatever. All performed in the way that doesn't affect the site.

Comment: If i turn off the MySQL server it takes 30 seconds for website to load + half the website issent loaded. I would say that is an effect on the site.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [mysqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php),

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

I further suppose you could check the [value of connect_errno](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-client.html) to get a better idea of why the connection failed.

Comment: It takes 30 seconds before "$mysqli = new mysqli(...)" timesout with a 2002 error but i need my website to be useable without this long wait on every page load.

Answer (score 2):

Most of web sites are not just "retrieve some data from the MySQL server and displays it", but have ALL the data stored in DB. So, a database server become a vital part of the site. With 2 consequences:

- there is no way for a site to "run normally" if a DB server is down
- there are reliable servers available with 99.99% uptime

So, nobody actually do such a verifications you are asking for - they are working on making a DB server 100% available, not on a verification if it's up or down.

So you have to.

Comment: My website isn't among most websites then. I just use MySQL for the voting system that displays a number and i don't see why failure in that should bring down the hole website.

Comment: I am also interested in the sense how mysql can response back that right now its low on resources or need a reconnect query with an interval ?

Answer (score 1):

each time you can give call to this function and check is server is running or not

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: How this answer supposed to help?

Comment: as user wants to check mysql server is running or not..above code is given for that only he can make little bit of modifications into it to suite hes needs.

Comment: I want to use the object oriented way. If i use "$mysqli = new mysqli(...)" there is a 30 seconds wait for a timeout. So my website hangs for 30 seconds.

Comment: The OP asked not how to connect. They have this code already. They asked actually "how to check if MySQL server is running **before** connecting to it"

Comment: I think else part gives the ans of his question...